# Swich from Java 6, 7 and 8

Tags: java, macos

I am working on Mac and I was wondering how I can switch easily from Java version without restarting my laptop.

Actually my Java is set in file `/etc/launchd.conf`

Comment: Does [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/juggling-multiple-versions) help? This kind of thing will never require a restart. You simply point to something else.

Comment: @ ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ the Java Preferences window  do no longer exist, I am on Mavericks OS, I am unable to find it in /Applications/Utilities

Comment: The interesting part is the one that talks about the different paths. Though there are better "tutorials" to help you switch between them.

Answer (score -1):

Just export a new JAVA_HOME.  You can have multiple running programs each using their own version of JAVA by setting JAVA_HOME in the runtime environment before running.